# PHP: Date in a raw and time in column, how can I set it

Tags: php, html, calendar

I am creating a simple date and time table for showing booking. I am struggling on the format which I want to create. How can I do this  ?
Exactly I want like in below format.

- Days starts from Monday
- Next link will load next 7 days
- Prev link will load past 7 days
  [image]

I have tried and manage to show 7 days with next - prev button & the code looks like

```
(int)$currentpage = (!empty($_GET["currentpage"]))?$_GET["currentpage"]:0;
(int)$nextpage = $currentpage + 1;
(int)$prevpage = $currentpage - 1;

<tr>
    <td><a href="<?php echo "{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?currentpage=$prevpage"; ?>"> << </a> </td>
    <td></td>
    <td><a href="<?php echo "{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?currentpage=$nextpage"; ?>"> >> </a> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 
$ts = date(strtotime('last sunday'));
$ts += $currentpage * 86400 * 7;
$dow = date('w' , $ts);
$offset = $dow;


$timestamp = strtotime('2009-10-22');
$day = date('D', $timestamp);


$ts = $ts - $offset * 86400;
for ($x=0 ; $x<7 ; $x++,$ts += 86400) {
    echo '<td>' . date("d-m-Y", $ts) . '</td>' ;

}

</tr>
```

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to build a calendar UI. This isn't a simple task, as you're discovering. My advice would be, don't re-invent the wheel, use a ready-made calendar UI library. There are a few around for web-based calendars. IMHO the most comprehensive and usable one is [fullCalendar](https://fullcalendar.io/). You can simply define the view(s) you want, point it to the source of some event data, and off you go.

Comment: And actually its built-in "time grid" view is almost exactly the same as what you're showing in your screenshot above - if you look at the demo on the home page and click on the "week" option, you'll see it.

Comment: @ADyson you are right but actually I want to show only the booking status from the date time in db. So I thought will go with this way.

Comment: "I want to show only the booking status from the date time in db"...that's exactly what a calendar plugin like fullCalendar is for. (N.B. I have no connection to that piece of software, I'm not part of the development of it or anything, I just think it's a very useful tool and would solve your problem quite easily.)

Comment: Anyway, it's unclear where you are stuck exactly with your requirement. You say you are "struggling" but that is not a clear description of your problem. I see from the code you have created the header part with the dates. So what exactly is preventing you from completing the rest of the rows showing the times? Is there something you don't understand? have you tried anything yet? Please be specific about your difficulty.

Comment: @ADyson yes I've tried to write a code for time with another loop, but I am not able to make it in one single loop. So based on date and time want to check ONLY the availability of the booking slot from the database.

Comment: Sorry but it's still unclear - in particular whether the issue is about outputting those times as per your screenshot, or whether it's something related to checking your database data (which we can't see, so can't help you with). We also don't know what output you want when there is availability in a particular date/time and when there isn't. Do you want the cell in the table to be highlighted or something? All you've shown in your screenshot is the basic empty grid, not anything about availability.